# Magento 2 GraphQl get store wise product collection

Tags: magento2.4.3, graphql

I want to get the product collection store-wise via graphQl. I have set in header parameter **"Store": "ar"**,
I want to get the product name in the Arabic store, but it's not working.

I have referred this
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/send-request.html#headers

Comment: define "it's not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got stuck in this issue for a while but i found the solution finally.
All you need adding the key:value below in Headers :

key => store
value => ar

as in screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0):

What GraphQL query are you running? To get products for a given store, I'd expect that you need to run the following query - presumably defining the store URL in the request

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/products.html